Connected lie subgroup in Hall Book

I am currently reading the chapter 5 of B.C Hall book of Lie algebra. Now, I dont understand what is the use of invoking this definition here instead of using normal "connected" lie subgroup definition.He has proved that for a connected matrix lie group we can write each element in the 3rd point's form but dont know if it is true for any general connected lie group.

What is the "normal" definition?

There is a unique analytic subgroup corresponding to each subalgebra. Defining it as just some corresponding Lie subgroup which is connected is not guaranteed (a priori at least) to be a unique selection.

@Callum I see.I got it.
